# Sum of column values in sharepoint list if value for another column matches using C# and CAML

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, sum, caml

I am trying to get the value of manager in the sharepoint list and when the manager values are the same, i'm trying to add all the amounts then output the manager name and the sum.

Here are the entries in the sharepoint list

```
Manager     Amount
1           1000
2           2000
3           3000
4           500
1           1500
2           2500
```

Then I should send an email that should have this output and return only the top 3 highest amounts:

```
Manager     Amount
2           4500
3           3000
1           2500
```

Here is my CAML Query

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = " <Query><Where><And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Manager' /></IsNotNull><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Amount' /></IsNotNull></And><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Amount' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Where></Query> ";
```

And Here is my Code

```
        double iSum = 0;

        foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
            FieldUserValue man = (FieldUserValue)oListItem["Manager"];
                if(oListItem["Amount"].ToString() == null)
                continue;
                iSum += Convert.ToDouble(oListItem["Amount"].ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("\nManager Name: " + man.LookupValue + " Amount: " + iSum.ToString());
            message += "<tr>"
                     + " <td class='pdetails'> " + man.LookupValue + "</td> "
                     + " <td class='pdetails'> " + iSum.ToString() + "</td></tr> ";
        }
```

Kindly help me in fixing my caml query and foreach loop and how to get the expected output which is the sum of the amounts per manager. Please and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SharePoint handy, so the list access code might not be quite right, but the rest of the code should do what you want.

```
ManagerSummary summary = new ManagerSummary();
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    FieldUserValue managerValue = (FieldUserValue)oListItem["Manager"];
    string managerId = managerValue.LookupId;
    string managerName = managerValue.LookupValue;
    double amount = Convert.ToDouble(oListItem["Amount"].ToString());

    summary.AddValue(managerId, managerName, amount);
}

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.AppendLine("<tr><th>Manager Name</th><th>Total</th></tr>");

foreach (var manager in summary.TopManagers(3))
{
    output.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", manager.Name, manager.Total);
    output.AppendLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());


class ManagerSummary
{
    Dictionary<string, Manager> _managers = new Dictionary<string, Manager>();

    public void AddValue(string managerId, string managerName, double amount)
    {
        if (_managers.ContainsKey(managerId))
        {
            _managers[managerId].Total += amount;
        }
        else
        {
            _managers[managerId] = new Manager { Id = managerId,  Name = managerName, Total = amount };
        }
    }

    public List<Manager> TopManagers(int count)
    {
        var managers = _managers.Values.ToList();
        return managers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total).Take(count).ToList();
    }


}

class Manager
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-10}", Name, Total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `GroupBy` to handle the grouping of managers for you, as well as the summing of all of the ammounts within a group.

```
var query = collListItem.OfType<ListItem>()
        .Select(item => new
        {
            Manager = (FieldUserValue)item["Manger"],
            Amount = item["Amount"] as double?,
        })
        .GroupBy(item => item.Manager.LookupValue)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Manager = group.Key,
            Amount = group.Sum(item => item.Amount),
        })
        .Select(group => string.Format(
@"<tr><td class='pdetails'>{0}</td>
<td class='pdetails'>{1}</td></tr>", group.Manager, group.Amount));

string message = string.Concat(query);
```

Comment: hi servy, however i need to use the string "message" in my code because it is used for me to send an an html formatted email. Below my code includes proj.sendMail(message); and I have a method sendMail for the email.

Comment: Hi, i tried using message += string.Concat(query); but i get the error (NotSupportedException was unhandled). Then i tried using message += query; and i get the error ->
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientQueryable`1[System.String]. What can i do about it?